# The Zero Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a $3\times 3$ matrix with all $0$ entries that is the coefficient matrix for a homogeneous linear system, what does this tell you$?$ I had someone try to tell me that this means that $x, y, z$ could be any $r\in\Bbb R$, but since all he coefficients are $0$ we don't have any defined variables right$?$ So the size of the matrix is arbitrary$?$ Would the answer then just be $\Bbb R$ $?$

Thank you!

Comment: "but since there's 0 coefficients" this is false. There are 9 coefficients and all of them are 0. Zero is a perfectly honest value for a coefficient.

Comment: The solution to the corresponding linear system.

Comment: Is that better quid?

Comment: Yes, this is clearer. It is still  a misconception, but this is fine and the point of the question. :-)

Comment: We have a defined _number_ of variables, but we can't make any restrictions onto the values they assume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any vector $v = (x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is trivially a solution of $0v = 0$. Indeed,

$$ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0x+0y+0z \\ 0x+0y+0z \\ 0x+0y+0z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

So the solution space is all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.